# javascript array of markers is undefined in google maps api 3

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps-api-3, maps

I try to move my markers on a Google map with positions I get from a XML file.
I create the markers and want to store them in an array.

```
markerArray[fzg] = marker;
```

Then I read the new positions and want to change the position of a specific marker in the array.
Every marker has an unique id called "fzg".

My moveMarker function always says: markerArray is undefined.

Can't find where the problem is

here the entire code without unnecessary fragments

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title></title>
<link href="swu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="map"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

function initialize() {
    //map
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.393866111111, 9.9770183333333),
        zoom: 16,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
        });

    //traffic
    var trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
    trafficLayer.setMap(map);
}

markerArray = [];

function createMarkers () {

            //for testing without XML file
            // create for every i 1 marker

            for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {

                var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(
                48.393866, 9.977018);

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: pos,
                });

                marker.setMap( map );

                //store marker in the array with index i
                markerArray[i] = marker;

          } // end for

          moveMarker(map, markerArray);

} // end createMarkers()


function moveMarker(map, markerArray) {

        for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {

        //move marker with index i on the map   
        //console says following markerArray is undefined

        markerArray[i].setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(48.393860, 9.9770199));

        }
    }

initialize();
createMarkers();
setTimeout(moveMarker(), 2500);
</script>



</body>
</html>
```

CSS file:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Where do you define the `markerArray`?  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling moveMarker without any arguments:

```
setTimeout(moveMarker(), 2500);
```

When it runs, markerArray is undefined.  Function signature is:

```
function moveMarker(map, markerArray)
```

One option to address this would be:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  moveMarker(map, markerArray)}, 
  2500);
```

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  //map
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.393866111111, 9.9770183333333),
    zoom: 15,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  });

  //traffic
  var trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
  trafficLayer.setMap(map);
}

markerArray = [];

function createMarkers() {

    //for testing without XML file
    // create for every i 1 marker

    for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {

      var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(
        48.393866, 9.977018);

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: pos,
      });

      marker.setMap(map);

      //store marker in the array with index i
      markerArray[i] = marker;

    } // end for

    moveMarker(map, markerArray);

  } // end createMarkers()

var increment = 0.001;

function moveMarker(map, markerArray) {

  for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {

    //move marker with index i on the map   
    //console says following markerArray is undefined
    var position = markerArray[i].getPosition();
    console.log("move marker " + position.toUrlValue(6));
    markerArray[i].setPosition(
      new google.maps.LatLng(
        position.lat(), (position.lng() + increment))
    );
  }
  // markerArray[i].setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(48.393860, 9.9770199));

}


initialize();
createMarkers();
setInterval(function() {
  moveMarker(map, markerArray)
}, 2500);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your call to the second function contains two parameters:

```
moveMarker(map, markerArray);
```

But the function is declared with only one parameter:

```
function moveMarker(map) {
```

`moveMarker()` is looking to a more global scope for `markerArray` and finding an undefined variable.